# giving users select-only permissions of database objects

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2017 with a production database called Biz. I'd like to

1. Give three users the ability to run SQL queries against this database without altering the data, *or maybe preferably,*
2. Create a separate database (or schema) called BizView with some commonly-used queries, tools, etc. Then I could give BizView the appropriate read-only permissions on Biz. Then my users could just log into BizView and run their queries from there. . . right?

All of my users are on a domain. What combination of logins/roles/permissions would allow this basic read-only reporting on my production database? It's so simple, but I feel like I'm mis-applying Oracle concepts (I'm newly responsible for this single MS-SQL database) to this situation.

Comment: It's not clear why do you want to create a separate database and not to create your views inside your Biz database. As soon as you add your users in db_datateader in **Biz** database they can not only "just log into BizView and run their queries from there" but they would be able to query Biz database directly

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to mimic an Oracle architecture that I inherited. The advice I received was "don't touch the production schema" because it belonged to a legacy app designed somewhere else. So any additional tools/reports/views we devised were put into a separate schema, which had Select permissions on the original one. It was a way of separating the Biz software from any add-ons that we desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want to give those users `db_datareader` and nothing else. This is pretty common.

> Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data
>   from all user tables.

See the role explained in the [MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to control what the users can see, since you mentioned views. Like only aggregated data from one table, or just some of the columns. If that is the case, an option is to create views for your users, put the views in a separate schema and then grant SELECT on just that schema. Either directly to each user or to a role that you added the users to.

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::reporting TO report_users
```